# How to check if class already exists in django?

Tags: django

I have a fabric that creates classes.

```
...Some code here...

def CreateClass(self, _context):
    classname = _context.__name__ + "Test"
    return type(classname, (viewsets.ModelViewSet,), {
        'set_of_objects':_context.objects.all(),
        'template_name': "base.html"
```

Then I have some class when I calls this fabric:

```
bla-bla-bla
    myClass = CreateClass(Foo)
```

I would like to customize behaviour for specific classes, so I want to create them manually.

for example I could create a class

```
class FooTest:
    set_of_objects = FooSerializer(smth here)
    template_name = "Foo.html"
```

The problem is, when I call this fabric it creates a FooTest class nevertheless it already exists in my app.

I would like to write a method that will allow me:

```
1. check if class with specific name already exist. (or is there some uniq class ID?)
2. If class already exist method should returns it
```

Could you please help me for first question? I checked some manuals but did not find a solution how can I do this.

I already try to use something like this

```
from django.apps import apps
cls = apps.get_model(app_label = 'base', model_name = 'FooTest')
```

The problem is, that this method is working, when FooTest is inherited from models.Model (from django.db import models)

But is it possible to know if class exist if it not inherited at all?
The ideal solution for me - to get a qualified class name.
For examle if you open shell and write smth like this

```
>>>from base.person.models.person import Person
>>>p = Person
>>>p
```

you probably receive smth like this

```
<class 'base.person.models.person.Person'>
```

How can I get this path *base.person.models.person.Person*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me perfectly fit a solution like this

```
".".join([_context.__module__, _context.__name__])
```